# Systemverilog assignment - logic array to byte array

Tags: system-verilog

I'm trying to assignment `logic l_data[31:0];` to `byte data[];`.

`data = l_data;` is not legal SystemVerilog assignment. How can it be done?

Comment: data is 8 bits l_data is 32 bits wide. Which bits of l_data do you want to assign to data?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a bit-stream cast (section 6.24.3 of the [IEEE Std 1800-2012](http://standards.ieee.org/getieee/1800/download/1800-2012.pdf) LRM). You will need to create a typedef for the cast, but it is a good idea to use typedefs for all your variable declarations anyways.

```
typedef byte unsigned dynamic_byte_array_t[];
typedef logic fixed_logic_array_t[31:0];

dynamic_byte_array_t data;
fixed_logic_array_t l_data;

data = dynamic_byte_array_t'(l_data);
```

A couple of notes:

1. Be careful using `byte`, it is signed by default.
2. I add a `_t` suffix to all my type basic names,
3. I suggest using more meaningful type names than what I have used here.
4. The bit-stream cast has one specific order to move bits-left-to-right. Use the streaming operator if you need more complex bit ordering (Section 11.4.14)